# Made in China Syndrome

Tags: management

I have stated some reliability and safety concerns about a product that so happens to be made in China. Sure I have proper engineering reasons for this and dont want anybody in the building to be  electrocuted when doing tests. I stuck to my guns about safety. My boss has had a complaint because I said China. She went crazy and mentioned Donald Trump which in my opinion has nothing to do with this.

There has been a complaint about me which I do not know where it came from. Apparently I am not allowed to mention China.       What advice do you have? My coworkers say that I must be more woke?

Comment: It sounds like you implied that the device was hazardous by virtue of being manufactured in China. It appears to me that you may have an implicit bias regarding China and you let it slip out. If a device is unsafe then it is unsafe regardless of it's origin.

Comment: Apple has lots of devices (if not all devices) such as iPhones, tablets, computers, etc... designed in the US and made in China. These products have great quality because Apple is a giant and reputable company that cares about the quality. So, if the companies in your post are reputable, their products can be highly reliable even if the products are made outside the USA.

Comment: "**She went crazy and mentioned donald trump...**". She tries to drag her own political points of view or preferences into a business discussion, which is inappropriate. So, in this case, the best thing to do is to ignore her political views, do not argue about politics at your workplace, and instead stay focused on the company business.

Comment: You can probably search the web to find out the safety ratings of each product from the real consumers. Then, you can present your results and recommendations to your manager. That research would be more convincing than just blindly telling her that all products made in China are unreliable, which is not true.

Comment: If you say "The legal regulations about safety and quality and whatnot in domain X are much stricter in country Y than in China", and you back that up with a source, then that's a reasonable argument. If you say "I don't trust anything that comes from China" then it's a lot less reasonable, and racist.

Answer (score 2):

If you "stuck my guns about safety", then why did you mention China at all?

List all the regulations the device breaks, put it in an email to create a paper trail. Further denial and you escalate to the legal team. It's relatively straightforward.

If you feel offended about the mention of Donald Trump, then you also have issues. They like to drag in political comments, so refuse to engage at that level and actually "stick to your guns" regarding safety.

Comment: I thought that politics did not enter the workplace ,I copuld not understand why it was mentioned ,I was not offended but thought it was unproffesional,

Comment: So did YOU mention China? If you did, then it was a political statement. If a device is unsafe, it is unsafe. It has nothing to do with its origin as @joeqwerty have said.

Comment: For this metaphor to be comprehensible it really needs to be "stuck *to* my/your guns about safety", i.e. "to" is not optional here. If you are sticking to your guns it means that you are insisting on something, that you are defending a position without backing down (perhaps stubbornly so), etc.

Comment: Sometimes you can't judge the safety of a device yourself, you have to trust the source. Each country has different regulations when it comes to safety, quality, environmental impact, labour laws, etc.; in this case, it makes sense to quote the regulations of the country the item comes from and to compare regulations across countries. If you're working in country X which has strong regulations about something, then you may not be allowed to use an item from country Y which has much lighter regulations about the same thing.

Comment: @Stef the source has no bearing on regulation. You can have safe and unsafe devices from China and the US. If the devices go through regulatory bodies such as UL, then you can contact UL to get the certification details and to confirm whether the UL testing is actually done or is a fake. If the concerns are regulated safety requirements, there are plenty of resources available to assess it, and the origin of the device has no real material effect.

Comment: @Nelson So the source country has no bearing on regulation, *if* it's a choice between the US and China. Other countries may have stronger regulations than these two.

Comment: Ok, replace any country with any country. Regulations are not based on the country, but the regulation. If you want to adopt UL regulation, then use the UL regulations to evaluate safety. I don't know why the country of origin affects this. You test it whether it is from US, UK, China, India, Canada, Mexico, Brazil, Cuba, Russia, etc. You test it against UL regulation.

Comment: @Nelson - Simply mentioning that there is a history of fake unsafe products coming out of China is political if the device is being purchased appears to be unsafe. Because there is a history of fake products, unsafe products, and unauthorized clones of products coming out of China. There are also perfectly safe products coming out of China. Actually bringing up a politicians policy is bringing up politics